# Spectrum and Bases of Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$f: F_3^2 \to F_3^2$, given by
$f(a, b) = (b, -a-b)$

Spectrum: roots of $\det(f-xI)$

- $A = [f(1,0), f(0,1)]$
- $A=[(0,-1), (1,-1)]$

Comment: I don't see a question.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix associated to the linear map is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
because $f(1,0)=(0,-1)$ and $f(0,1)=(1,-1)$.

The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial:
$$
\det(A-xI)=\det\begin{bmatrix}
-x & 1 \\
-1 & -1-x
\end{bmatrix}=
x^2+x+1=x^-2x+1=(x-1)^2
$$
since we're in the three element field.

There is only one eigenvalue, that is, $1$; for the eigenvectors, we want to solve the linear system $(A-I)v=0$, which has as matrix
$$
A-I=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the vectors in the eigenspace are those of the form $(k,k)$, because if $v=(v_1,v_2)$, both equations reduce to $v_1=v_2$.